# What is max input voltage on ATMega4809 (datasheet versus Atmel-ICE programmer)?

Tags: voltage, atmega, maximum-ratings

**Background**

I have my ATMega4809-pf hooked up properly and I am able to program it via my Atmel-ICE programmer.

**Problem**

However, when I read from the chip using the Microchip Studio it warns me that my 5.4V which is applied is out of range and that the chip really has a max of 5V.

When I read from the chip using the programmer it shows this warning:

[image: voltage warning]

When I click [Yes].  It reads the chip as expected.

[image: atmega4809 programmer info]

That link to the datasheet leads me to the datasheet details I show below (which contradict what the programmer tells me).

**Datasheet Says 5.5 Volts max**

However, the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega4808-09-DataSheet-DS40002173C.pdf) tells me (if I'm reading it correctly) that the chip can take 5.5V max on VDD.

[image: max input voltage]

That previous chart from the datasheet may have been related to ADC but I found this one for VREF also:

[image: vref voltage max]

Which one of these should I believe?
Or, am I reading the datasheet incorrectly or something?

Answer (score 1):

The Atmel ICE programmer does not supply power to the device being programmed, instead it connects to VCC and reports the voltage being applied.

Measure the voltage on your MCU with a multimeter and verify whether the voltage reported by Microchip Studio is correct or not.

The datasheet also has an "Absolute Maximum Ratings" section which shows the value you should not exceed (6V) or risk damaging the component:

[image: Absolute Maximum Ratings]

In the case of the datasheet giving one value (5.5V) for the operating range while the IDE gives another (5.0V), I would believe the datasheet over the IDE. However, it's entirely possible that one of those values is newer than the other. Look for errata for the chip, updated datasheets, etc. The drivers/support in the IDE for the chip are most likely based on the datasheet, so it may just be a data error on someone's part making the support package. When in doubt, ask the manufacturer to be sure. (We've found lots of mistakes in Atmel datasheets and brought them up to our FAE.)

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough but I'm know I'm not powering the device from the Atmel-ICE -- I have a external power supply which is supplying the 5.3V.  But I was wondering why the programmer is reporting a max value on the chip that is lower (5V) than what datasheet says (5.5-6V)

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that max value (which is 6V and is even higher than the Atmel-ICE thinks is allowed).  Maybe the ICE is just older and providing the wrong value but would think this is read from the chip or something.

Comment: @raddevus Ah I see what you're asking now: Whether the 5.0V operating range from Microchip Studio or the 5.5V value given in the datasheet is the correct one. I'd wager the datasheet, because the board support packages (or whatever Atmel/Microchip call them) are going to be based on the datasheet as well, in my estimation. When in doubt, ask the manufacturer, though.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was asking.  And like you're saying, "when in doubt, ask the manufacturer..." both the datasheet and the atmel-ice programmer are made by microchip.   
I'm thinking the datasheet showing 6V max is the correct answer though.
thanks for all your help.

Comment: @raddevus Just to further clarify - the 6V is the absolute max, but it isn't meant to be operated there. When I say ask them, I mean you have to write or call and get them to tell you where they screwed up. Either the datasheet or the IDE support is incorrect, so it may be worth asking them so they can get it fixed for future reference. (But I'm willing to bet the 5.5V is the correct value.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.   I will keep all of this in mind as I move forward.

Answer (score 0):

When interfacing with signals greater than recommended values , the heat rises with rapid rates, but if not using much power, that isn't too significant. Yet RdsOn drops with the square of the voltage above Vt.  The transitions are going thru shootthru .

Also interfacing with voltages greater than diode drops above remote supply with 10k ESD R current limiting on the remote device is also a concern if incorrect sequencing occurs. It's called the SCR Latchup and self destruct effect on big Chips..

It worked but be aware of the effects.